# INSERT INTO two different tables, but have the same ID?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database of Users and another table for Teachers. Teachers have all the properties as a user but also an e-mail address.  When inserting into the DB how can I insert the info, ensuring that the ID is the same for both?

the ID currently is on automatic incrament.

this is what I have at the moment:

```
$sqlQuery="INSERT INTO user(firstName,lastName,DOB,title,password,classRoomID) 
    VALUES('$myFirstName','$myLastName','$myDOB','$myTitle','$newPassword','$myClassRoom')";
    $result=mysql_query($sqlQuery);

$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO teacher(email) VALUES ('$myEmail')";
$result=mysql_query($sqlQuery);
```

thank you!

Comment: Use mysqli, mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why to use separate table for teachers. instead, you can have email field with in user table and additional field with flag (T ( for teacher) and U (for user). Default can be a U. This have following Pros.

1. Will Not increase table size as email would be varchar
2. Remove extra overhead of maintaining two tables.
3. Same Id can be used

If you want to have that as separate table then answer you selected is good one but make sure last insert id is called in same connection call.

Comment: I tried to normalise it by having users, and then teacher and student tables. But I am slowly starting to see the benefits of just having one user table.

Answer (score 4):

use MYSQL function LAST_INSERT_ID()
OR php mysql https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$sqlQuery="INSERT INTO user(firstName,lastName,DOB,title,password,classRoomID) 
    VALUES('$myFirstName','$myLastName','$myDOB','$myTitle','$newPassword','$myClassRoom')";
    $result=mysql_query($sqlQuery);

    $id = mysql_insert_id();

$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO teacher(id, email) VALUES (' $id ','$myEmail')";
$result=mysql_query($sqlQuery);
```

Comment: This way unfortunatly didn't work for me, but below did.

Comment: I think both are equal except it uses mysqli and I use mysql function ..... Check and try updated answer .....

Answer (score 2):

After the first insert, fetch the last inserted id:

```
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id(); // or mysql_insert_id() if you're using old code
```

Or you could expand your second query and use mysql's integrated [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function:

```
$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO teacher(id, email) VALUES ((SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()), '$myEmail')";
```

Answer (score 1):

**Insert data into two tables & using the same ID**

First method

```
$sqlQuery1 = "INSERT INTO user(firstName,lastName,DOB,title,password,classRoomID) VALUES('$myFirstName','$myLastName','$myDOB','$myTitle','$newPassword','$myClassRoom')"; 
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQuery1);

$lastID = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

$sqlQuery2 = "INSERT INTO teacher(email, lastID) VALUES ('$myEmail', 'lastID')";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQuery2);
```

If the first method not work then this is the **second method** for you

```
$sqlQuery1 = "INSERT INTO user(firstName,lastName,DOB,title,password,classRoomID) VALUES('$myFirstName','$myLastName','$myDOB','$myTitle','$newPassword','$myClassRoom')"; 
$result1 = mysqli_query($sqlQuery1);

$sqlQuery2 = "INSERT INTO teacher(email) VALUES ('$myEmail')";
$result2 = mysqli_query($sqlQuery2);
```

You can **set the Foreign Key** in your database **table** (phpMyAdmin/ MySQL Workbench) to **let the** **Foreign Key follow the Primary Key** (**ID**). Then the **data after insert** will **auto-follow the Primary Key ID**.

**Example here,**

Teachers table set **ID** - Primary Key

Users table set **UserID** - Foreign Key (will follow the Teachers table ID)

if you're using MySQL WorkBench, you can refer to this link to set a foreign key.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor-foreign-keys-tab.html

Hope I can help any of you.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function in order to get the last insert id, the best approach in this case is to create a column reference to user id table.

```
teacher

id | user_id | email
```

So the `teacher.id` could be anyting, but the `user_id` column is the real reference to `user` table.

If you use `InnoDB` table, you can make the database consistent using [Foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Answer (score 0):

You Should Use A Transaction In MySQL. First insert In One Table And GET `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.
Insert `LAST_INSERT_ID()` In Second Table.

```
    $sqlQuery="INSERT INTO user(firstName,lastName,DOB,title,password,classRoomID) 
        VALUES('$myFirstName','$myLastName','$myDOB','$myTitle','$newPassword','$myClassRoom')";

$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO teacher(LAST_INSERT_ID(), email) VALUES (' $id ','$myEmail')";
$result=mysql_query($sqlQuery);
```